# How to layout fields correctly

Tags: blackberry

I've been trying to layout fields in blackberry and when I think I have it working I try another simulator and my field's are laid out differently.

If I call `setPositionChild(field, 0, 100);` I would expect on all phone resolutions that
the fields would be positioned at position x=0, y=100. This is not the case.

Reading the RIM doc for setPositionChild, the y parameter is - "y - Offset of the top of the field in its manager." The y offset returned by field.getTop is consistently 0, so position should be consistent across screens? Maybe a good explanation of how setpositionChild works would suffice.

Thank you.

Comment: Layout is the result of the complex interplay of a number of methods in the manager and its children. It might help if we could see the code.

Comment: Also, almost every different BlackBerry model has a different display height and width and dot pitch.  As such, you will likely want to use sizes/positions that are relative instead of fixed.  For example, for a button to take up half the screen, you would need to set its width to `Display.getWidth() / 2` instead of some static value (e.g. 160px).  And then you have to consider re-layout when the user rotates the device between portrait/landscape...

Comment: This page has a nice listing of BB device screen details for some of the more recent devices: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/28627/Designing_for_different_BB_devices_software_6_1_1514767_11.jsp?CPID=TWDresolution081211

Comment: Did you try to use setMargin ?
I think that it will do the trick and maybe you will not have any issue

Comment: Those positions are relative the the parent Manager's top left, not the screen. If the Manager isn't actually at (0,0) on the screen, your Field will have an offset. Try setting a border on the Manager and giving it a margin of 0 so you can see exactly where it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your variable results are from extending [MainScreen](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/MainScreen.html). That class contains separators etc that will be offsetting your 0,100 to something else.

Either try using [FullScreen](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/FullScreen.html) which is a single [VerticalFieldManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.7api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/VerticalFieldManager.html)
Or override sublayout on your MainScreen and set its width and height to the full size of the display.